# Webdriver (C#) - Looping and appending name of element inside array to a screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Here is what I want to do:**

1. Get a handle on a dropdown menu
2. Get a handle on each of the dropdown menu options
3. Loop through clicking each option from the menu and then take a screenshot

**And here is what I have so far:**

```
                IWebElement DropDownMenu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='DropDownMenu']/span"));

                IWebElement Option1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Option1']"));
                IWebElement Option2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Option2']"));
                IWebElement Option3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Option3']"));

                var MenuOptions = new[] { Option1, Option2, Option3 };

                foreach (IWebElement Option in MenuOptions)
                {
                    DropDownMenu.Click();
                    Option.Click();
                    ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
                    Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
                    this.imageDisplay.Image = img;
                    sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle,"C:\\MyFileName.gif",ImageFormat.Gif);
                }
```

**What I'm struggling with:**

After looping through each item in the array, I need to create a screenshot.  the screenshot needs to be unique so as not to overwrite the first screenshot created inside the loop.  So essentially, (based on code sample above), I should have three screenshots created in "C:\".  MyFileNameOption1.gif, MyFileNameOption2 etc

So I assume I need some form of counter and append the item name to the screenshot that's created but I'm lost at this point

**Just to clarify (and update my original answer):**

I need to actually get the name of each element in the array and then append this (as text) to the end of the file name.

Comment: You could use a counter, or perhaps append a GUID? Can you clarify on whether you just want direction on how to create unique filenames?

Comment: Just replace "MyFileName.gif" with a string to which you append a new number on every cycle of the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        IWebElement DropDownMenu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='DropDownMenu']/span"));

        IWebElement Option1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Option1']"));
        IWebElement Option2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Option2']"));
        IWebElement Option3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Option3']"));

        var MenuOptions = new[] { Option1, Option2, Option3 };
        string filename = "c:\\image"; //File location
        string extension = ".gif"; //File extension
        int i = 0; //File counter initialization


        foreach (IWebElement Option in MenuOptions)
        {
            string filenameNew = filename + i.ToString() + extension;
            i++;
            DropDownMenu.Click();
            Option.Click();
            ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
            Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
            this.imageDisplay.Image = img;
            sc.CaptureWindowToFile(this.Handle, filenameNew, ImageFormat.Gif);
        }
```